# Use Reference or Collection method to access navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

What does it mean and how to solve it?
The property 'LanguageTo' on entity type 'OrderItem' is being accessed using the 'Property' method, but is defined in the model as a navigation property. Use either the 'Reference' or 'Collection' method to access navigation properties.

I have entity OrderItem which has LanguageFrom and LanguageTo properties. There is IdLanguageTo property which is foreign key into table (entity) Language. In language entity is ICollection OrderItemLanguageToNavigation property.

In context configuration I have:

```
entity.HasOne(d => d.LanguageTo)
    .WithMany(p => p.OrderItemLanguageToNavigation)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.IdLanguageTo)
    .HasConstraintName("FK_OrderItem_Language_IdLanguageTo");
```

Maybe problem is there:
private abstract class BeforeChangeEntry : BeforeEntry, IBeforeChangeEntry {
            protected BeforeChangeEntry(TEntity entity, TDbContext context, Boolean cancel) : base(entity, context, cancel) {
                original = new Lazy(() => Context.GetOriginal(Entity));
            }
            private readonly Lazy original;
            public TEntity Original => original.Value;
        }

It is piece of code from EntityFrameworkCore.Triggers library. I looked for it and there is open issue about it. I follow solution and make navigation property as virtual, exception is not going but I cannot get to parent object when there is change on child object.

Comment: The exception is not caused by the shown code. Search the code for `Property` method referencing `LanguageTo` property of the `OrderItem`. Something like `context.Entry(orderItem).Property("LanguageTo")` or similar. Actually it should be the code line where the exception occurs - can we see it?

Comment: Instead of describing your entities in words, what prevents you to paste the code of actual classes?

Comment: It should be from third party library - EntityFrameworkCore.Triggers.